# How to read Ultrasonic sensor value to use and drive servo motors

Tags: sensors

I would like to know how i can use my ultrasonic value in an if else statement, so i can use the value that the servo motors stop running and go in another direction when the ultrasonic sensor gets close to an object.

```
/*
  Digital pin 2 is connected to a switch
  Digital pin 3 is connected to a switch
  Digital pin 7 is connected to the echo port of the ultrasonic sensor
  Digital pin 8 is connected to the trig port of the ultrasonic sensor
  Digital pin 9 is connected to a servo
  Digital pin 10 is connected to a servo
  Digital pin 13 is connected to a LED

 */

#include <Servo.h> // include a special file that is needed for servo motors, do this only once

Servo motor1; // create a servo object for each motor
Servo motor2;

int echo = 7; //declare echo from ultrasonic sensor
unsigned long duration;
void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
    pinMode(2, INPUT);
    // switch 2 initialize
    pinMode(3, INPUT);
  // initialize the servo on pin 9
  motor1.attach(9);
  // motor 2 initialize
  motor2.attach(10);
    // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    //echo pin of ultrasonic sensor
    pinMode(echo, INPUT);
    //trig pin of ultrasonic sensor
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
      // the trigger pin sends a pulse
       digitalWrite(8, LOW); 
       delayMicroseconds(2); 
       digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
       delayMicroseconds(10);  
       digitalWrite(8, LOW);
       duration=pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
      // the echo pin measures how long it took for that pulse to come back
       Serial.println(duration); 
      // delay in between reads for stability
       delay(50); 
       duration=pulseIn(echo, HIGH);


  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH: 
  if(duration <=400) {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    // turn the motors off for 2 seconds
    motor1.write(90);
    motor2.write(90);
    delay(2000);
    //turn motor 1 on for 2 seconds to make a turn
    motor1.write(180);
    delay(2000);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    //motors run when vehicle is not near objects
    motor1.write(0);
    motor2.write(180);
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem so far? Does the code not work? Please be more specific.

Comment: The sensor shows me all the values in the console but i dont know how i can use those values in an if else statement so that my servo motors would stop and turn around when the sensor gets close to an object. The code works when i use a switch in the if else, but now i want to use the ultrasonic sensor to be the switch in stopping the servo motors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would make sure I have continuous servo motors that can rotate 360 degrees. Your servos will just rotate to the degree you entered if they are not continuous. Additionally, it would be more helpful if you named your pins. For example:

```
int echo = 7;
void setup(){
    pinMode(echo, INPUT);
}
```

This will help us read the code better.

I also see that you have "pulseIn" in your if statement. You must save the value to a variable with the data type of unsigned long.

```
//before the setup 
unsigned long duration;

//keep your setup as it is


void loop(){
   digitalWrite(8, LOW); 
   delayMicroseconds(2); 
   digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(10);  
   digitalWrite(8, LOW); 

   duration=pulseIn(echo, HIGH);

   if(duration<=400){//check for the value
       // turn LED on:
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        // turn the motors off for 2 seconds
        motor1.write(90);
        motor2.write(90);
        delay(2000);
        //turn motor 1 on for 2 seconds to make a turn
        motor1.write(180);
        delay(2000);
   }else{
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        //motors run when vehicle is not near objects
         motor1.write(0);
         motor2.write(180);
       }
   }
```

Overall: check your servos and save the value of pulseIn to a variable. You might also want to convert to centimeters by dividing duration by 58.2.

Comment: the led goes on now when i put my hand in front of the sensor and off when i get my hand away, but the motors do not continue running. When before they would just go on forever

Comment: @S.Mateijsen What power source are you using? So the LED goes off, motor 1 stops and motor 2 is already stopped? And they just stay at rest?

Comment: im using 4 AA batteries and my laptop as power, the led stays on untill i remove my hand(thats also whats supposed to happen so the led works) the motors just rotate a bit around and then stop at there angles

Comment: turned out my batteries where almost empty :< But now the motors both go on at the start. after a couple seconds the led goes on and he makes a turn. but he keeps making turns now and doesnt go right ahead anymore so he keeps looping the if duration <=100 statement and doesnt come to the else part.

Comment: First check your batteries. Maybe they are dead. It happened to me yesterday. A servo was working and then in the middle it always shut off. Can you confirm that they are continuous servos? Post a picture of them or a link where you got them. The phrase "at their angles" confuses me. Do the servos stop at 0 and 180 degrees? If yes, then they are not continuous.

Comment: If you are using your computer for power, the chances are that your computer is in the way of the sensor. It might always read low values and trigger the if statement. Try using a 9V battery to power the arduino and out the robot on the floor in an open space without obstructing the sensor.

Comment: It would also be helpful for you to post the updated draft of the code you are using now.

Comment: The servos are continuous servos they keep running now(problem was the batteries) I also tried to put it in on open area where nothing would be in front of the sensor but it keeps looping the "stopping and making a circle part" instead of going straight ahead. and i updated the main post with my current code.

Comment: Try reading the Serial Monitor and seeing if the duration values actually change. You might have a defective sensor. Also, does the LED turn off in a wide area or no?

Comment: The sensor puts the values out like every 2 seconds in the console with a value of 7000 so it shouldnt be doing the <=100 statement at all. The LED also stays on in an open area.

Comment: What if you put your hand in front of the sensor? Still 7000? Also do Serial.println(duration) not Serial.println(pulseIn(7)). The second option will cause the duration to become 0 after printing because the signal will have already been collecting and pulseIn will return 0 the second time.

Comment: i updated the main post again, the sensor gives me the values now and when i put my hand infront of it it becomes like 200 and when i dont the values is around 17000.

Comment: That is not what I meant with Serial. First save pulseIn to duration. Only then print it out and then do the if statement. If you called pulseIn twice, the second time will give you a 0 and the first time will give you the right value.

Comment: Cheers man! that was the problem it works perfectly now :D